# Contact form fields not responsive/won't scale

Tags: html, forms, css, responsive-design

Here is the form HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="/cgi-bin/Contact.pl"  id="contact-form">
  <div id="wrapping" class="clearfix">  
    <section id="aligned">  
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name..." autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" class="txtinput" data-validate="validate(required)">  
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email..." autocomplete="off" tabindex="2" class="txtinput" data-validate="validate(required, email)">  
     <textarea name="message" type="text" id="message" placeholder="Message..." tabindex="3" class="txtblock" data-validate="validate(minlength(20))"></textarea> 

   <div id="buttons">
      <input type="reset" name="reset" class="button" tabindex="4" value="Clear">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" tabindex="5" value="Send">
   <br style="clear:both;">
   </div>
</section>
```

Here is the corresponding css:

```
#contact-form { 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /*Firefox 1-3*/
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari */    
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    }
#contact-form .txtinput { 
    display: block;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #DEDEDE;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 11px 25px;
    padding-left: 55px;
    width: 90%;
    color: #777;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    transition: border 0.15s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.15s linear 0s, color 0.15s linear 0s;
    -webkit-transition: border 0.15s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.15s linear 0s, color 0.15s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: border 0.15s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.15s linear 0s, color 0.15s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: border 0.15s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.15s linear 0s, color 0.15s linear 0s;
    }
#contact-form .txtinput:focus { 
    color: #999;
    border-color: rgb(255, 102, 0);
    border-color: rgba(255, 102, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.6);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.6);
    outline: 0 none; 
    }
#contact-form #name {
    background: #FFF url('../images/contact/user.png') 5px 4px no-repeat;
    }
#contact-form #email {
    background: #FFF url('../images/contact/email.png') 5px 4px no-repeat;
    }
#contact-form textarea {
    display: block;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #DEDEDE;;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 11px 25px;
    padding-left: 55px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 180px;
    color: #777;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset; 
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    transition: border 0.15s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.15s linear 0s, color 0.15s linear 0s;
    -webkit-transition: border 0.15s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.15s linear 0s, color 0.15s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: border 0.15s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.15s linear 0s, color 0.15s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: border 0.15s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.15s linear 0s, color 0.15s linear 0s;
    }
#contact-form textarea:focus {
    color: #999;
    border-color: rgb(255, 102, 0);
    border-color: rgba(255, 102, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(153, 153, 153, 1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(153, 153, 153, 1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(153, 153, 153, 1);
    outline: 0 none; 
    }
#contact-form .txtblock {
    background: #FFF url('../images/contact/speech.png') 5px 4px no-repeat;
    }
#contact-form #slider { width: 60%; }
#contact-form #aligned { 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    float: left; 
    width: 450px; 
    }
#wrapping { width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

Everything works fine until I display on a smaller device/screen then the fields don't act responsively and kind of overflow out of the box and onto the background as can be seen in the image provided in the link. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Link to example: http://www.livepurposely.net/image.png

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Maybe the #contact-form elements paddings should not be defined as pixels but percents ? Try to adjust these parameters in your browser's inspector or create a [jsfiddle](jsfiddle.net) as asked before.

Answer (score 1):

In your css you are restricting width of `#aligned` to 450px and using px in padding, its better to use % in padding for responsive design

**Info:** px constraints the width to specified unit and is not good for responsive design, use % instead

Update CSS

```
#contact-form .txtinput {
   padding: 3% 5%; // earlier 11px 25px
   padding-left: 2%;
}

#contact-form textarea {
   padding: 3% 5%;
   padding-left: 2%;
}

#contact-form #aligned {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    width: 90%; // earlier it was 450px update % as per your need
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/nh5aZ/2/